# Spring Data Mongo: mapping objects using Jackson annotations

Tags: groovy, jackson, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using spring-data Mongo (1.3.3) as a mechanism for accessing Mongo.
My domain objects are written in Groovy and I use Jackson annotations to define properties and names:

```
@JsonProperty('is_author')
boolean author = false
@JsonProperty('author_info')
AuthorInfo authorInfo
```

When I persist one of my domain objects to Mongo, the JsonProperty annotation is ignored and the field is persisted using the standard object's field name.
By digging in the Spring Data Mongo [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.core.html), I **found out** that the library expects a `@Field` annotation to modify the actual field's name in Mongo.

Is there a way to use only the Jackson annotations instead of using two annotations to achieve the same results. Maybe a "customized" version of MappingMongoConverter?

Comment: If you're using Groovy 2.1+, could you use the AnnotationCollector? http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/groovy-goodness-combining-annotations.html

Comment: That's exactly what I did! I was going to update the question, but you were faster. Thanks!

Comment: Hehe, you did all the work! ;-)  Maybe post what you did as an answer to this question?  I know I'll upvote it ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Since my application is in Groovy, I have used the new `@AnnotationCollector`AST Transformation (http://blog.andresteingress.com/2013/01/25/groovy-2-1-the-annotationcollector-annotation/) to "merge" the Jackson and the Spring Data Mongo annotations. Here is how it looks like: simple and effective!

```
package com.someapp
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty 
import groovy.transform.AnnotationCollector 
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field 
@AnnotationCollector([Field, JsonProperty]) 
public @interface JsonMongoProperty {}
```

And here is how it is used:

```
   @JsonMongoProperty('is_author')
   boolean author = false
   @JsonMongoProperty('author_info')
   AuthorInfo authorInfo
```